# Add class to radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="1" >
 <label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span>1</label>
<input id="radio2" type="radio" name="rgroup" value="2" >
 <label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span>1</label>
```

I have something like this and i want to add an image to the element which is checked using javaScript. How can i do it?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? img tag is part of  HTML  code.

Comment: I want to check if the answer is correct and if it is to add a green tick.

Answer (score 6):

Is it important for you to add a class for the radio which is checked? As you can do that simply with CSS:

```css
#radio1:checked + label {
    color: #f00;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8vQ9/)

```css
#radio1:checked + label:after {
    content: url(IMAGE_URL_HERE);
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8vQ9/1/) (With image embedded when you select the radio box)

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/g8vQ9/6/) (With tick image)

Comment: How can i put the tick into the radio button(in the circle)?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the checked radio:

```
function getCheckedRadioId(name) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByName(name);

    for (var i=0, len=elements.length; i<len; ++i)
        if (elements[i].checked) return elements[i].value;
}
```

Then add the image to the checked element.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";

var src = getCheckedRadioId(rgroup);
src.appendChild(img);
src.parentNode.insertBefore(img, src.nextSibling);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-image: url("");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center left; /* or center right */
}
```